# A hard city in which to be unsuccesful

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What does "in which" mean here? It looks like the sentence can be split in "a hard city in which" and "to be unsuccesful", but, anyway, I do not understand the first part. Does it mean "city was severe for the loosers?"

> He stopped to wait in line outside a coffee shop, but the line wasn’t
> moving. He would’ve left if he had somewhere to be, but he didn’t,
> unlike the men hurrying past in their frock coats. Their frowns were
> due to preoccupation, not disappointment. Palermo was **a hard city in
> which** to be unsuccessful.

Lisa Scottoline "Loyalty"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that it was difficult to live as an unsuccessful person in Palermo; but turning the sentence round to make Palermo the subject. So, yes, it does effectively mean what you suggest.